# When to use "cerca de" vs "cabe"

Tags: preposiciones

I recently learned the preposition ***cabe*** means close "*to/by*". How do I know when to use ***cabe*** versus ***cerca de***?

Various sites provide the definition of *cabe* a close to and reference *cerca de*. I just can’t find a guideline for when or where to use each.

Comment: Short answer: "cabe" is old-fashioned and never used nowadays. Use "cerca de".

Comment: cabe from the verb caber is used in other ways.

Comment: I've never heard anyone using "cabe" that way. Great question.

Answer (score 3):

As [DLE says](https://dle.rae.es/cabe):

> **cabe**
> [...]
> 1.prep. desus. Cerca de, junto a. U. en leng. poét.

i.e., it is not used anymore ("desus."), and when it is used, it is in poetic language. So just use "cerca de".

Answer (score 3):

Como cualquier otra preposiciones, "**cabe**" es invariable, es decir, no tiene género ni número.

En la actualidad es raro el uso de esta preposición, pero se puede encontrar en algunos textos literarios y por otra parte no debe confundirse con la conjugación del verbo "caber".

La preposición "**cabe**" **se utiliza de forma indistinta como sinónimo de** "**cerca de**" o "**junto a**".

Ejemplos con la conjunción "cabe";

- En el teatro Ricardo se sentó **cabe** la famosa directora de cine.
- La empresa se encuentra **cabe** el pueblo.
- La parada de taxis está **cabe** la estación de autobuses.
- Los mejores libros, los venden en la tienda que está cabe la farmacia.
- Cuando llegaba del instituto, vi que mi amigo me esperaba **cabe** la puerta.
- El gato duerme **cabe** al ratón.
- Cambiaron la rueda del autobús **cabe** el camino.
- Los niños jugaban **cabe** la orilla del mar.
- La oficina de Pedro Luis está **cabe** la mía.
- Alicia estaba en el parque y quiso sentarse **cabe** los cisnes.
- Como hizo mucho frío, se sentaron **cabe** la chimenea.

**Nota**: Actualmente todos estos ejemplos se dirían con el adverbio de lugar "**cerca de**" o con la conjunción "**junto a**" ya que el anterior enunciado, aunque posible, resulta obsoleto.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple: use *cerca de* whenever you want to be understood, and *cabe* whenever you want to get puzzled looks.

The preposition *cabe* is never used nowadays. Most people just learn that it exists at school, and I bet the vast majority of Spanish speakers don't even know what it means or how to use it.